# Apply HTML and CSS style to Java Swing component

Tags: java, html, swing, jtable

I have to write a multi-line text inside the header cells of a **JTable**.

For this reason, I'm using **HTML** this way (this is an example):

```
     JTable.getModel().getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setHeaderValue("
    <html>
          <div style='width:100%;height:300px;overflow:hidden'>
               <div style='width:100%;height:150px;overflow:hidden'>
                       text of line 1
               </div>
               <div style='width:100%;height:150px;overflow:hidden'>
                        text of line 2
               </div>
         </div>
   </html>
    ");
```

I want set the inner div a **100% width** and **150px height**. 
But seems that **height**, **width** and **overflow** doesn't work.

What is my error?

Comment: The Swing HTML rendering engine (a subset of HTML 3.2) does not support most CSS. I doubt it would handle `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: Thank you. I used a <table> because I had to force every line not to break, so I used <td nowrap>, accepted by HTML 3.2 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to write a multi-line text inside the header cells of a JTable.

Keep the HTML simple:

```
setHeaderValue("<html>Line1<br>line2<br>&nbsp</html>");
```

The above will allow for 3 lines of text (for all columns of the header).

Note: the height of the header is determined by the height of the renderer in the first column.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used a <table> because I had to force every line not to break, so I used <td nowrap>.